# Unit test with equal DateTimeOffset dates returning error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, fluentvalidation, xunit.net

I'm making an Unit test for a Request with dates. These dates are with the same timestamps and the test is failing. With different timestamps the test is running well, but with equal timestamps the test is returning an error result.

Code for test:

```cs
[Fact]
public void ShouldHaveValidationSuccessWhenStartDateIsLessOrEqualToFinishDate()
{
    //Arrange
    var request = new RegisterRequest { FinishDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, StartDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow };
    var sut = new RegisterRequestValidator();

    //Act
    var result = sut.TestValidate(request);

    //Assert
    result.ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.StartDate);
}
```

Code for validator:

```cs
public RegisterRequestValidator()
{
    RuleFor(req => req.StartDate).LessThanOrEqualTo(req => req.FinishDate).When(HasStartDate);
}

protected bool HasStartDate(RegisterRequest req) => req.StartDate != null;
```

Code for RegisterRequest:

```cs
public sealed class RegisterRequest : IRequest<OperationResult<IQueryable<EntityViewModel>>>
{
    public DateTimeOffset? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? FinishDate { get; set; }
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Message: 
    FluentValidation.TestHelper.ValidationTestException : Expected no validation errors for property StartDate
    ----
    Validation Errors:
    [0]: 'Start Date' must be less than or equal to '07/11/2019 12:50:58 +00:00'.
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: Try `var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow; var request = new RegisterRequest { FinishDate = now, StartDate = now };` Doing that will assign the same value for both the FinishDate and StartDate instead of having a new and possibly different value generated when you call it

Comment: or simply change the order of properties in object initializer.

Comment: @Sinatr that would still not satisfy the test case for them both being equal - but rather hide the underlying problem.

Comment: @germi, what test? I see `LessThanOrEqualTo`.

Comment: The OP wants to test that the validator works correctly when supplying the same date for both properties (*"but with equal timestamps the test is returning an error result*"). When `.UtcNow` is called twice, that case will never be tested.

Comment: It works. Thanks @Igor and guys

Comment: @germi Yes, I want to test if the validator is running well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting a different result from `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` because it is being called twice in the `RegisterRequest` constructor. Try:

```
var utcNow = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
var request = new RegisterRequest { FinishDate = utcNow, StartDate = utcNow };
```

Comment: This is a common pitfall. The `UtcNow` property makes you think it returns a consistent value, but almost every invocation of this property returns a **_different_** value. They should have made this a static method, rather than a property.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your request like this

```
var request = new RegisterRequest { FinishDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, StartDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow };
```

will lead to `StartDate` being *later* than `FinishDate` (albeit by only a few ticks). If you want to set both to the same, request the date once and set the same value for both `FinishDate` and `StartDate`:

```
var date = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
var request = new RegisterRequest { FinishDate = date, StartDate = date };
```

Answer (score 1):

Because these are not the same dates. You execute DateTime.UtcNow twice, and there is a slight difference between them. You could see it more easily if you checked request.StartTime.Ticks and request.EndTime.Ticks.

Answer (score 1):

The dates used are **not the same**. Every time you read the UtcDate you get the **current** date. Use a constant date for your tests.